# Why do file system need though DB exist?

Tags: database, filesystems

Why do file system need though DB exist?
In my opinion, if DB exists under VFS and DB-to-block level connector exist between DB and block level, then it can be faster and safer than current file system.
What do you think about it? Or already there is a answer of this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Relative DBMS are not very well suited to holding heterogeneous data, and most of them hold large BLOBs (and most files would be large BLOBs) in the filesystem in one way or another.
2. Microsoft spent lots of time and effort trying to make your idea work. They didn't succeed completely (although many pieces of what they had created went into NTFS later).
3. Oracle holds several patents on representing DB contents as a hierarchical filesystem and in storing a filesystem in the DB (the thing close to what you are asking about).